# ¿Cómo detectar versiones de ECMAScript de lo navegadores?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Esto si que no me ha sido fácil de encontrar, pero con ayuda de kangax.github.io hice algo:

```
var ES5     = typeof window.Worker === 'function',
    ES51    = typeof Date.prototype.toISOString !== 'undefined',
    ES6     = '__proto__' in {},
    ES7     = Array.prototype.includes;
```

Quizás haya alguien quien pueda apoyarme para mejorar la detección de ECMAScript? Por ejemplo, ES3?.

Comment: Puedes preguntar y responderte tu mismo, no es necesario que pongas la solución en la misma pregunta.

Comment: ¿Dónde se definen y qué valores tienen las variables `HTML5test` y `caniuse`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Disculpa la falta de documentación. Ya modifiqué arriba.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para que realmente sea una pregunta sobre un problema concreto, y añade una respuesta con la solución al problema. De lo contrario la pregunta será cerrada.

Comment: La frase "_Zepto1.x vs jQuery2.x, gana Zepto por ser más liviano y rápido_" es subjetiva y, en mi opinión, debería ser eliminada. Habrá gente que considere que jQuery gana porque soporta más navegadores que Zepto, o porque tienes más métodos que Zepto, o porque una vez cargado jQuery es más rápido, o porque tiene más plugins disponibles en este momento...

Comment: @Konamiman , que difícil es poner un título :) Falta de práctica :P. Pero ya lo cambie.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, cierto tu comentario en lo que se refiere a lo subjetivo. Sin embargo, a que sea eliminado no lo comparto, ya que el contenido puede ser importante para muchos o para pocos. Solo es cuestión de corrección y corrección. Gracias al moderador por dar oportunidad de mejorar.

Comment: Hola @JamesPeter, te comento que este sitio no es un blog. Si quieres compartir una solución a un problema que has encontrado puedes hacerlo publicando una pregunta y una respuesta independientes, no juntandolas en el mismo post.

Comment: @JamesPeter solo me refería a esa frase en particular, no a la pregunta en sí, que está bien

Comment: @JamesPeter Me parece que no me has entendido. No te sugería que mejoraras el título (cosa que de todas formas también está bien), sino que editaras la pregunta para que fuera realmente *una pregunta*, y que después añadieras una respuesta conteniendo *la respuesta a la pregunta*. Te sería útil explorar otras preguntas del sitio para hacerte una idea de cómo funciona, y leer esto: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yo no creo que deba eliminarse, uno de los propósitos de stack overflow es compartir el conocimiento, en lo que si estoy de acuerdo es que necesitas editarla y poner tu respuesta a la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @CarlosMuñoz . Haciendo caso a tu comentario, hice las respuestas independientes lo cual veo que queda mucho mejor. Gracias por los comentarios positivos.

Comment: @JamesPeter creo que no has entendido, no me gustaría que toda el post que has creado se pierda, puedes ingresar al chat y con gusto conversamos sobre el tema: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @JamesPeter Por favor haz lo siguiente, creo que será la mejor solución: 1) Añade una respuesta con una copia del contenido actual de la pregunta. 2) Edita la pregunta para que sólo contenga los enunciados de las subpreguntas. 3) Y por la naturaleza de la información, creo que es conveniente que la respuesta sea convertida a wiki.

Comment: @Konamiman, entiendo un poquito del 1) y del 2), pero lo del 3 está clarísimo. Como dice CarlosMuñoz, es un Post para WebLog o como tú, un WiKi. Por tanto, terminaré con una sola pregunta del todo, para así mejorar mi script. Gracias moderadores.

Comment: @JamesPeter te falta escribir la respuesta tomando como base la versión anterior de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que con 01 comentario fue suficiente para dar respuesta a mi pregunta. Aquí expongo lo resumido de mi consulta:

```
    var ES1     = !!(Array.prototype && Array.prototype.join),
        ES3     = !!(Array.prototype && Array.prototype.pop),
        ES51    = (function() {'use strict'; return !this; })(),
        ES6     = !!Object.assign,
        ES7     = !!(Array.prototype && Array.prototype.includes);
            /*
            var ES51    = Modernizr.es5,
                ES6     = Modernizr.es6object;
                ES7     = false;
            */

        if(ES7){
            alert('Tu navegador contiene características mínimas de ECMAScript 7');
        }else if(ES6){
            alert('Tu navegador contiene características mínimas de ECMAScript 6');
        }else if(ES51){
            alert('Tu navegador tiene soporte para ECMAScript 5.1');
        }else if(ES3){
            alert('Tu navegador contiene características de ECMAScript 3');
        }else if(ES1){
            alert('Tu navegador contiene características de ECMAScript 1');
        }else{
            alert('Tu navegador contiene características de ECMAScript desconocida');
        }
```

Comment: En esta pagina hay muchos tests que pueden servir para validar la compatibilidad con cada característica de cada version. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/

Answer (score 3):

No te serviría utilizar [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Este te permite validar si el browser implementa ECMAScript y la versión.
Analiza la documentación de la librería allí lo menciona.

Comment: He revisado la documentación de Modernirz, y en efecto; existe métodos para detectar características de ECMAScript 5 y 6. Pero solo son características, mas no versión. Y cierto es que no es fácil ya que los fabricantes de navegadores de poco a poco vienen implementando  características, tal es el caso del ES6 y ES7. Pero si detectáramos todas las características de una versión específica, creo que ahí podemos decir que el navegador soporta el estándar ECMACscript versión X. Tal es el caso de:  var ES51 = Modernizr.es5;